# Is there a reason my javascript file is not recognized?

Tags: javascript, html, npm, electron

**index.js:**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 400,
    height: 450,
    icon: __dirname + '/icon.png',
    title: "Password Generator",
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
  mainWindow.removeMenu()

  // Open the DevTools.
  //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

**generator.js:**

```
const resultEl = document.getElementById('result');
const lengthEl = document.getElementById('length');
const uppercaseEl = document.getElementById('uppercase');
const lowercaseEl = document.getElementById('lowercase');
const numbersEl = document.getElementById('numbers');
const symbolsEl = document.getElementById('symbols');
const generateEl = document.getElementById('generate');
const clipboard = document.getElementById('clipboard');

const randomFunc = {
    lower: getRandomLower,
    upper: getRandomUpper,
    number: getRandomNumber,
    symbol: getRandomSymbol
}

clipboard.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    const password = resultEl.innerText;

    if(!password) { return; }

    textarea.value = password;
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    textarea.remove();
});

generate.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const length = +lengthEl.value;
    const hasLower = lowercaseEl.checked;
    const hasUpper = uppercaseEl.checked;
    const hasNumber = numbersEl.checked;
    const hasSymbol = symbolsEl.checked;

    resultEl.innerText = generatePassword(hasLower, hasUpper, hasNumber, hasSymbol, length);
});

function generatePassword(lower, upper, number, symbol, length) {
    let generatedPassword = '';
    const typesCount = lower + upper + number + symbol;
    const typesArr = [{lower}, {upper}, {number}, {symbol}].filter(item => Object.values(item)[0]);

    // Doesn't have a selected type
    if(typesCount === 0) {
        return '';
    }

    // create a loop
    for(let i=0; i<length; i+=typesCount) {
        typesArr.forEach(type => {
            const funcName = Object.keys(type)[0];
            generatedPassword += randomFunc[funcName]();
        });
    }

    const finalPassword = generatedPassword.slice(0, length);

    return finalPassword;
}

function getRandomLower() {
    return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 97);
}

function getRandomUpper() {
    return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65);
}

function getRandomNumber() {
    return +String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 48);
}

function getRandomSymbol() {
    const symbols = '!@#$%^&*(){}[]=<>/,.'
    return symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Password Generator</h2>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <div class="result-container">
        <span id="result"></span>
        <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
        <button class="btn" id="clipboard">
            <i class="far fa-clipboard"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="settings">
        <div class="setting">
            <label>Password length</label>
            <input type="number" id="length" min='4' max='20' value='20' />
        </div>
        <div class="setting">
            <label>Include uppercase letters</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="uppercase" checked />
        </div>
        <div class="setting">
            <label>Include lowercase letters</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="lowercase" checked />
        </div>
        <div class="setting">
            <label>Include numbers</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="numbers" checked />
        </div>
        <div class="setting">
            <label>Include symbols</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="symbols" checked />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-large" id="generate">
        Generate password
    </button>
</div>
<style>
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
</style>

    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
        <script>require('/generator.js')</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "password-generator",
  "productName": "Password Generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Password generator desktop app",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "build-installer": "electron-builder",
    "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\""
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "password-generator"
  },
  "win": {
    "target": [
      "nsis"
    ],
    "icon": "src/icon.png"
  },
  "nsis": {
    "installerIcon": "src/icon.png",
    "uninstallerIcon": "src/icon.png",
    "uninstallDisplayName": "Password Generator",
    "oneClick": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "JipBit",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "password_generator"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.52",
    "electron": "9.1.0"
  }
}
```

**Updated Error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'generator.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\mel\Desktop\Password Generator 1.0\password-generator\src\index.html
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797)
    at Function.i._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:42)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74)
    at index.html:46
```

**Information:** All these files are under the folder src. I've tried to change the path and add src but that did not make a difference. I had this problem yesterday and got someone to answer my question which told me to require it in my HTML file. It did end up working afterwards, but I started a new project because I was having packaging issues. I'm now back to the same problem, and requiring the generator.js file has not fixed anything. The app opens perfectly fine without errors, but the javascript isn't functioning and its almost non-existent. It is meant to print text on the screen when I hit generate, but nothing seems to show up. I'm currently using the electron framework by GitHub. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I would suspect `<script>require('/generator.js')</script>` the `/` at the front says that generator.js is at the root of the web app. I would try removing that.

Comment: removing the / did not change anything. I'm pretty sure I already tried that I should've mentioned it my bad.

Comment: Try ./generator.js if both index.html and generator.js are in the same directory

Comment: Thank you so much Jay! I'm kinda mad at myself for making such a small mistake.